# Are all the eigenvalues of Antisymmetric matrix must be imaginary (ti)?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

(The field is $R$ - reals)
Antisymmetric matrix ($A^t=-A$) is a normal matrix ($A^tA=AA^t$) because $A^tA=-AA=-A^2$.
$$AA^t=A(-A)=-AA=-A^2\ .$$

So, are all the eigenvalues of $A$ have to be imaginary ($t=a+ib$ where $a=0$) ?
It makes sense but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to use latex, warp all the math in $ from both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the same matrix in the complex space; this does not change the eigenvalues. Now if $Au=\lambda u$, then $\lambda||u||^2=(u,\lambda u)=(u,Au)=-(Au,u)=-(\lambda u,u)=-\bar\lambda||u||^2$. Thus, $\lambda=-\bar\lambda$ and hence $\lambda$ is pure imaginary. However, as @Surb rightly says, if you exclude zero from imaginary numbers, the statement will  not be true.

Comment: Umm where did you use the fact the A is anti-symmetric ? (A^t=-A)

Comment: @Ron When writing $(u,Au)=-(Au,u)$ (in general, $(u,Au)=(A^*u,u)$, but the matrix is real-valued and so $A^*=A^t=-A$).

Comment: Ohh right, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. The $0$ matrix has only real eigenvalues (0) and is anitsymmetric. You can also consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1&  0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ then $A\neq 0$ is antisymetric and has $0$ as eingevalue since it is not invertible.
But as shown by Vladimir, the only possible real eigenvalue of an antisymmetric matrix is $0$.

Comment: This depends. The usual convention is that all numbers of the form $ai$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, are imaginary. (Thus, $0$ is real and imaginary simultaneously.)

Comment: @Vladimir Ok, I never thought at that. I edited my post and tried to take into account your comment.